# use HtmlHelper for creating jQuery UI dialogs

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

Html helpers are good, and jQuery UI dialogs are easy to use.

I wonder if I can create an `HtmlHelper`, that can simplify use of dialogs.
I mean to create and use even simple `jQueryUI` dialog you have to put some html and little piece of javascript.

Instead I'm trying to create a helper class, that will provide me similar functionality like we have in `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox`.

Is that possible, or there is better ways to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can - I did it : ) Its a bit messy but I have one.

actually.. download the code for the entire mvc project I did as a talk at:
http://completedevelopment.blogspot.com/2011/04/learning-mvc-for-web-forms-developer.html

look in the dialogfunctions.js code and the extensions folder for the extension methods for this.

Comment: Oh... I actually already downloaded it. I learned many new tricks but missed that dialogfunctions.js. I'll look at it. Thank you!